# How to save iphone screen shot as jpeg image?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on an app where I need to save a part of iphone's screen shot as JPEG and then send this through email. The part of screen has some text labels, fields etc. Any ideas please on how can I save part of screen as JPEG (I am a newbie therefore any help/sample code is highly appreciated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will save the contents of a view to the user's photo library. You should be able to modify it to be able to email the file instead.

```
  CGRect myRect = [myView bounds];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myRect.size);

  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  [[UIColor blackColor] set];
  CGContextFillRect(ctx, myRect);

  [myView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

  UIImage *image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  // Replace the following line with code that emails the image
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image1, nil, nil, nil);
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://blogs.zdnet.com/mobile-gadgeteer/?p=1278:

When you are on a screen that you want to capture, press and hold the Home button and then press the the power/sleep button. Your screen shot will then appear photo gallery on your iPhone where you can send it or sync it as needed.

Comment: Exactly, I was looking for a coding solution to this. Nevertheless, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a QuartzCore library.

See this one:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2353-possible-make-screenshot-programmatically-2.html